# Передача active из листа типа GameObject в лист bool

Tags: c#, unity3d

Объясните как передать active из листа с типом GameObject в лист типа bool ?

Comment: Перебором, например.

Answer (score 0):

```
var boolList = GameObjectList.Select(a=> a.active).ToList();
```